# Spark: write timestamp to parquet and read it from Hive / Impala

Tags: apache-spark, hive, timestamp, impala

I need to write a timestamp into parquet, then read it with Hive and Impala.

In order to write it, I tried eg

```
my.select(
 ...,
 unix_timestamp() as "myts"
 .write
 .parquet(dir)
```

Then to read I created an external table in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
  ...
  myts TIMESTAMP
)
```

Doing so, I get the error

```
HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable
```

I also tried to replaced the unix_timestamp() with

```
to_utc_timestamp(lit("2018-05-06 20:30:00"), "UTC")
```

and same problem. In Impala, it returns me:

```
 Column type: TIMESTAMP, Parquet schema: optional int64
```

Whereas timestamp are supposed to be int96.
What is the correct way to write timestamp into parquet?

Comment: I found a related issue: https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-17275 looking for a workaround

Comment: You could create the table first, then use SparkSQL to _INSERT_ into that table, managing automatically the compatibility issues... No offense meant, but I believe the Spark code base would do a better job that your hasty "workaround".

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:  a UDF that returns a java.sql.Timestamp objects, with no casting, then spark will save it as int96.